# Probablity of Choosing Correct Set of Numbers When Multiple Repeating Numbers Are Required

Tags: probability, probability-theory, contest-math

Suppose I have to select 10 random numbers from 1-10 to match some previously selected random number. I know the probability of any single set of numbers being selected correctly is 1 in 10 billion. However, what if I knew the set of numbers fulfills **one** of the following two requirements:

1. There will be 1 number that repeats itself at least 3 times (not necessarily consecutively) and 1 number that repeats itself at least twice. For example: 7775243389 (7 repeats 3 times, 3 repeats twice) and 6678709436 (6 repeats 3 times, 7 repeats twice) are valid sets/selections. 6677832154 is not valid (missing single number that repeats 3 times).
2. There will be 3 numbers that repeat twice (again not necessarily consecutively). Example of valid set: 6648492102 (6,4 and 2 repeat twice). Example of non valid set: 6648492105 (only 6 and 4 repeat twice).

Note: In both cases a number may repeat more than two or three times, these are both minimum values.

I know that in both of these cases the probability of me choosing a correct set is far better than one in 10 billion (since there are much less numbers to choose from) however I am not quite sure what the exact formula is to calculate the probability in each case.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have $n$ total digits the number of sequences with one digit three times, one digit twice, and no other repeats is ${n \choose 3}{n-3 \choose 2}\frac {10!}{(13-n)!}$ where the first factor chooses the locations of the three matching digits, the second chooses the locations of the two matching digits, and the last chooses the digits.  This has a maximum at $n=13$ of $46\ 702\ 656\ 000$.  You can get rather close to $1$ in $10$ billion with $n=12$ where it is about $14.37$ billion.

For three pairs and length $n$ you have $\frac 1{3!}{n \choose 2}{n-2 \choose 2}{n-4 \choose 4}\frac {10!}{(13-n)!}$ where the logic is similar but you get the leading $\frac 1{3!}$ because you can choose the three numbers to pair in $3!$ equivalent ways.  This gives about $9.34$ billion at $n=13$, which is very close.

The choosing of positions for the duplicated digits brings you a lot of extra possibilities compared to $10!=3\ 628\ 800$.

Comment: Thank you. What if there is no predefined location? The location of the repeating digits could be anywhere. Also there could be other repeats but it is not required (so 7778382444 is a valid choice). Finally, are you able to explain it in a bit less mathematical terms as I don't have a good background in math. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I didn't have a predefined location.  The choose factors are the number of ways to choose the locations of the matching numbers.  Having chosen them you fill in the rest.  That accounts for all possible locations of the matching numbers.  Do you understand $n \choose 3$ as the number of combinations, not permutations, of three items chosen from $n$?  Without that it is hard to give an answer.  Allowing other matches complicates things considerably, but it is hard to explain the overcounts that happen if you don't follow this answer.